# Add migration path from MSO to MSE

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close

Can we have a migration path from here to MSE, for questions that belong there?

This can be temporary, during the first few weeks/months of the split.

Comment: What Martijn said. But being someone mostly limited to MSO historically, I didn't know that, either!

Comment: Related / Follow-up post: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250152)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, because migration to MSE is not an option on *other* metas either.

**This** is your town hall. Bugs belong here too! There appears to be a misconception that site bugs can only be handled on MSE, this is not the case!

If a post really is meant to be handled at the central government site that is Meta Stack Exchange, then a moderator will migrate it, not the community.

To quote [Tim Post (Community Manager)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250073/100297):

> You don't have to go to MSE unless you want to, the community team and your moderators will take care of handling migrations for you, as they're needed.
>
> Put simply, MSE isn't something you even need to know about or think about, unless you want to.

and in a [chat conversation](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1983002#1983002):

> What we want to *stop* is the 'you did something wrong, you should have gone here!' brow-beating that 's been going on. That just deflects new participants with potentially huge ideas.
>
> After [the community management team gets] a firmer grasp of what we've been sending there, we might open a migration path, but not for a while.

And another from [Oded (Stack Exchange developer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250118/deleting-a-bad-post#comment513_250118), in response to someone wanting to migrate a bug post to MSE:

> We have **always** had bugs raised on child metas and we always looked at them on all metas. MSE is not the central bug repository.

and [this comment by him in the same thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250118/deleting-a-bad-post#comment507_250118)

> please. It is **relevant** here. No need to close/migrate it

Comment: Why shouldn't the community handle it?

Comment: @Stijn: because such migrations are *exceptional*, and something the local civil servants / moderators can handle just fine. Let the local 'government' determine if something needs to be escalated.

Comment: Even though I disagree, the question is answered I suppose. Will accept when I can.

Comment: @George You got me. I get off on closing questions. :)

Comment: I kind of disagree with the entirety of this post. The whole point in forking off a parent site to be the meta of all metas was so that it could handle issues which affect the entire exchange. Bugs (which are not site specific) affect the entire exchange. For example, the post you quote Oded talking about is being migrated right now to MSE. Moreover, the fact that this path does not currently exist for all metas does not mean that cannot change in the future and/or is not in the works right now.

Comment: @TravisJ: No, that post is **not** being migrated. It was merely closed as off-topic by community members, and **incorrectly so**.

Comment: @TravisJ: And word from Oded **and** Tim Post that migration is not needed nor required should just be ignored? The point of the split as to keep Stack Overflow stuff out of MSE, **not** to keep MSE stuff out of MSO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - No. It was off topic and should be on the meta which handles issues that cover the entire exchange. Community members vote to close posts as needing to be on other exchanges on a daily basis. This places them for review by moderator but never directly migrates. Also, you are taking Tim Post's comment out of context. He said you don't have to do it, they will take care of it. Not that it didn't need to happen.

Comment: @TravisJ: that's where the misconception lies. Those comments **specifically** state that the post is not off-topic.

Comment: @TravisJ: They state that **if** it is needed, they will take care of it.

Comment: @TravisJ: Specifically, [this comment by Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250118/deleting-a-bad-post#comment507_250118): *please. It is **relevant** here. No need to close/migrate it*

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That is not what it was set up for though. The whole point of this was to centralize repetitive information. Should every single meta now contain a post about this bug? No, of course not now that MSE is available. They forked MSE off in order to minimize duplication, not increase it. While Oded is a very smart person, I must also respectfully disagree with him as well on this issue. Tim Post spearheaded this, and if he had said that it would have been contradictory to every other post he put out on the MSE fork.

Comment: @TravisJ: So, a developer stating that *the way it has worked for all other child metas* is not good enough for you?

Comment: @TravisJ: And Tim **never said** that the split was about keeping bugs centralized and not on MSO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Not in that context, no. The way it **has** worked changed. So that is not really relevant. The way it **will** work is what this conversation is about. And it seems from all of the material posted prior to the fork, that going forward issues which affect the entire exchange should be at MSE.

Comment: @TravisJ: and you did see [Tim's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250118/deleting-a-bad-post#comment515_250118) in that same comment thread, right? *Folks are welcome to post on their meta site, where they feel familiar and comfortable. We'll handle migrating things to MSE. For the most part, folks will just participate on their per-site metas, which is fine. So much less confusion.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters - He didn't have to. It wasn't just bugs, it was about any issue which affected the entire exchange (exchange-wide bugs included)

Comment: @TravisJ: and that's quite apart from the fact that there is the possibility that that closed post *only applies to Stack Overflow*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yes, to reduce the confusion that they **should** be placed at MSE but are not yet since it is new and people are still adapting to it.

Comment: @TravisJ: From everything I've seen, the Community Team expects MSE to become a lot quieter as things are handled in child metas *mostly*. But never mind; it is clear we disagree on the interpretation here, so only Tim Post seems to be able to clear this deadlock.

Comment: Users can go to _their_ meta site to report any bug. The developers as well as the community team patrol _every_ meta site, MSO included - we've done this for years. We'll worry about migrating anything that should be migrated to MSE, with the help of per-site moderators by and by. Don't _worry_ about where someone posts a bug or feature request, part of the _main_ point of this was to alleviate the 'where does this go' confusion. Just go to your own town hall, if it needs to go to the capital city, we'll send it over.