# Community user incorrectly changing links from MSO to MSE

Tags: bug, edits, community-user

See my question here: [Dealing with answers which just link to "possible duplicate" and copy a snippet from it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251767/dealing-with-answers-which-just-link-to-possible-duplicate-and-copy-a-snippet)

The community user automatically edited the post to change the link from Meta Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Exchange, even though the post is on MSO (it had been migrated from MSE to MSO before I had posted the question).

Comment: Someone done a wrong assumption in coding a link fixer; clearly the linked ID is over 250000.

Comment: Yes, the script was indiscriminate - it was written pre split and didn't take the IDs into account. Sorry!

Comment: Eek, probably should have anticipated this while anticipating migrations. Chalking this one up to my bad.

Comment: same went [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251305/821057)

Comment: @TimPost Same for [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250145/add-migration-path-from-mso-to-mse#comment621_250145)